# Python Regex doesn't match . (dot) as a character

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex that matches all three characters words in a string:

```
\b[^\s]{3}\b
```

When I use it with the string:

```
And the tiger attacked you.
```

this is the result:

```
regex = re.compile("\b[^\s]{3}\b")
regex.findall(string)
[u'And', u'the', u'you']
```

As you can see it matches you as a word of three characters, but I want the expression to take "you." with the "." as a 4 chars word.

I have the same problem with ",", ";", ":", etc.

I'm pretty new with regex but I guess it happens because those characters are treated like word boundaries.

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks in advance,

## EDIT

Thaks to the answers of @BrenBarn and @Kendall Frey I managed to get to the regex I was looking for:

```
(?<!\w)[^\s]{3}(?=$|\s)
```

Comment: It obviously won't match a 4-character anything if you tell it it must match exactly 3 characters.  What exactly are the rules you want to use to decide if/when to match a fourth character?

Comment: I don't whant it to match, I just want `you.` to be treated as 4-char words so it doesn't match the regex

Comment: What characters do you want to count as word boundaries?

Comment: Just blank spaces and ends of line

Comment: Can you please accept an answer? Also, why are you using `\Z` and not `$`? I think they will do the same thing in this case, but `$` is more recognizable.

Comment: Yes it works with $ too, I'll change it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make sure the word is preceded and followed by a space (and not a period like is happening in your case), then use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
(?<=\s)\w{3}(?=\s)
```

If you need it to match punctuation as part of words (such as 'in.') then `\w` won't be adequate, and you can use `\S` (anything but a space)

```
(?<=\s)\S{3}(?=\s)
```

Comment: He clarified in a comment that he doesn't want to match the punctuation; rather, he wants the period to be counted as a word character so it prevents the "word" `you.` from matching (because it is more than three characters).

Comment: Your example still won't work, because `\w` will not match periods.

Comment: Thanks guys!! I found the solution! I didn't know about lookarounds.

Comment: This regex requires words to always have whitespace round them, so it won't match your first and last word.

Comment: you could probably fix this by using `(?<=\s|^)` and `(?=\s|$)` for the lookarounds though

Answer (score 1):

As described in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> A word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric or underscore characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric, non-underscore character.

So if you want a period to count as a word character and not a word boundary, you can't use `\b` to indicate a word boundary.  You'll have to use your own character class.  For instance, you can use a regex like `\s[^\s]{3}\s` if you want to match 3 non-space characters surrounded by spaces.  If you still want the boundary to be zero-width (i.e., restrict the match but not be included in it), you could use lookaround, something like `(?<=\s)[^\s]{3}(?=\s)`.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my approach. Also matches words that come right after punctuations.

```
import re

r = r'''
        \b                   # word boundary
        (                    # capturing parentheses
            [^\s]{3}         # anything but whitespace 3 times
            \b               # word boundary
            (?=[^\.,;:]|$)   # dont allow . or , or ; or : after word boundary but allow end of string
        |                    # OR
            [^\s]{2}         # anything but whitespace 2 times
            [\.,;:]          # a . or , or ; or :
        )
    '''
s = 'And the tiger attacked you. on,bla tw; th: fo.tes'

print re.findall(r, s, re.X)
```

output:

```
['And', 'the', 'on,', 'bla', 'tw;', 'th:', 'fo.', 'tes']
```